# select in tree vs join , which is better in hive?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, database-performance

I have a query which is roughly

```
select * from A join ( select * from ( select * from C ) join B on B.id=C.id) D on A.id=D.id
```

which is equivalent to

```
select * from A join B on A.id = B.id join C on C.id
```

Each table contain more than 100k rows and there are no where clause but in place of * there can be lesser number of field.
Which one is better in performance.